# subprocess call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to execute the following command in terminal for multiple files
`SetFile -c "" -t "" <FileName>`
so I created a python script that would take filenames as arguments and use call function to execute the command. But I don't know how to put those "" marks in call pipe.
here is the code

```
from subprocess import call
import sys # for sys.argv
def main():
    l = len(sys.argv)
    l = l - 1
    if(l>0):
        for i in range(l):
            termExecute(sys.argv[i])

def termExecute(argument):
    call(["SetFile", "-c ","","-t ","","argument"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am pretty sure the `call(["SetFile", "-c ","","-t ","","argument"])` is wrong I hope to know the right way of writing it.

edit:

```
Akuls-MacBook-Pro:~ akulsanthosh$ python3 /Users/akulsanthosh/Documents/Simple/Setfile.py /Volumes/akul/Stuff/1.jpg /Volumes/akul/Stuff/2.jpg /Volumes/akul/Stuff/3.jpg 
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: argument 
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: argument 
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: argument
```

Comment: @bulbus ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: ""-t "" 
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file:  
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: argument

Comment: Sorry, couldn't answer it in comments so put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call(["SetFile", "-c ",'""',"-t ",'""',"argument"])`

Python treats both `'` & `"` as valid string delimiters, thus this is possible. Even otherwise you can escape the quotes. In fact you've used string with `'` delimits with `'__main__'` in your code.

After looking at the errors you're getting I would try the below
`call(["SetFile", "argument"])`

Comment: Invalid type or creator value: '""'
Invalid type or creator value: '""'
ERROR: File Not Found. (-43)  on file: argument

Comment: Can you run the command in your CMD/shell with those inputs and paste the working command here?

Comment: Add the working command (outside of python) to your question, that way it would be easier.

Comment: I meant run it with a proper Filename and paste the command and output.

Comment: As per the error shown`Invalid type or creator value:` which is different from first error. It seems SetFile is confused if you send it `""`.

Comment: I believe `-c` should be for `creator` and `-t` should be for `type`

Comment: Cool, let me know if you've any questions or mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), you can pass empty strings:

> *args* is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. **Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names).** If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

You can also pass quotes: "''"